# How to do tokenization from a predifined vocab in tensorflow or pytorch or keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, pytorch

I have a predefined vocab which build from the common-used 3500 Chinese characters. Now I want to tokenize the Dataset with this vocab to fix each character. Any mature `class` or `function` exists I can inherit from to buid the data reading pipline?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than go through the how to details here  I suggest you go to a tutorial on YouTube located [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzWbbqgjV9g&list=PLs_CQl4mUvI7Z9HnwoeOS5EUu9gyvekjK&index=120&ab_channel=GabrielAtkin). The author demonstrates how to use the tokenizer to encode text characters into sequences which can then be used as input to an embedding layer. The part you will be interested in starts at time 23:30 of the video